# How do you globally changing tags in Plone?

Tags: tags, plone, categorization

Plone has a neat categorization feature of content using tags and a tag cloub. I would like to change the name of a tag globally. Instead I have to find every page and change it that way. Is there an easier way to just rename the tag and have it apply to everywhere it is used? We are using Plone 4.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the addon PloneKeywordManager: http://plone.org/products/plonekeywordmanager.

Comment: This looks like it will do the job. I'll have it installed. Thank you for the quick response!